# Images not aligning to center of a bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just started learning to code and have been stuck trying to make my images center on a bootstrap row. I've tried applying the center-block div to each image which centered them, but vertically one after the other. I applied center-block to the row which does nothing and I also created divs before and after the row to test if that would work but it did not. I tried text-align: center; on all the different divs with no luck as well.

```
<div class="row">
 <img class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 img-responsive" src="img1.png">
 <img class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 img-responsive" src="img2.png">
 <img class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 img-responsive" src="img3.png">
</div>

.center-block {
  float: none;
}
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap 3 or 4?

Comment: Using 3. Sorry, forgot to mention that. Also the row is inside of a container and jumbotron if that matters.

Comment: If you were using bootstrap 4, you could do it with a helper class like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqNyGg

Comment: You could also do that same technique using bootstrap3 and custom classes. I'm not sure of a "bootstrap" way of doing it using bootstrap3. Would you like me to write some custom css that would work with bootstrap3?

Comment: That would be very helpful. I'll study your code and try to comprehend where I went wrong for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some custom CSS you can apply to bootstrap3 that will mimic the built-in `flexbox` classes you can use with bootstrap4. Just make the row that holds the columns `display: flex` and use `justify-content: center` to center the columns horizontally.

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center flex-row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly but unfortunately I don't know why as I've never encountered flex before. Do you know why everything I tried before didn't work?

Comment: bootstrap 3 uses `float` to create it's columns. And you can't use `text-align: center` to center floated elements, since that only applies to `inline/inline-block` elements, and a floated element is `block`. And `.center-block` with `float: none` will just make the image `display: block; margin: auto;`, which will break the columns since they're no longer floated.

Comment: @learningtowebdev here's a good resource on flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2):

You can use that easy way to center them inside of row or another div.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
 <img class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 img-responsive" src="img1.png">
 <img class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 img-responsive" src="img2.png">
 <img class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 img-responsive" src="img3.png">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row{
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
}

.row img{
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood problem, but hope it will be useful. xD
If you want to center your .row across the all page - use col-xs-4 (because bootstrap uses 12 columns, if you have 3 blocks, then 12/3 = 4 (for each div)).

If you knew it, sorry. When I'm using text-align: center to div, everything works.

Yes, bootstrap uses `float: left`, but that is on `col-*-*` elements, but when you write `.col-*-* {text-align: center}`, you position not that div but everything what's inside this div.

Really hope something was useful. :)

Comment: I'm using col-xs-3 col-md-1 because I want the images to be quite small. I tried text-align: center; on the col-*-* divs but it didn't work. Here is the codepen for the FCC project I'm working on if you want to take a look: https://codepen.io/Zed20/pen/PjNmer

Comment: If you want images smaller, just add css: img {width: 75%} for example. For centering row you need to use col-xs-4, or with col-offset-*. It is solution which I realise all the time on my job, we use only that for centering multiple elements. ;)